# \n is not working in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to unix and trying to run the following command using my shell script "setup.sh"

```
if [ `grep -c 'pro-ad-assembly-0.1' /usr/local/conf/jobserver.conf` =  0 ]; then
    sed -i "\$aspark {\n  jobserver {\n    job-bin-paths {\n      ad-scala=\"/opt/scala/pro-ad-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\"\n    }\n  }\n}" /usr/local/conf/jobserver.conf
fi
```

but jobserver.conf is not updating as expected and returning

```
include file("/hb/data/spark/job-server/jobserver.conf")
spark.context-settings.memory-per-node = ${SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY}
spark {n  jobserver {n    job-bin-paths {n      advisor-scala="/opt/scala/pro-ad-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"n    }n  }n}
```

as New line character is not working and n is remaining while updating the jobserver.conf

When i am trying to run the

```
if [ `grep -c 'pro-ad-assembly-0.1' /usr/local/conf/jobserver.conf` =  0 ]; then
    sed -i "\$aspark {\n  jobserver {\n    job-bin-paths {\n      ad-scala=\"/opt/scala/pro-ad-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\"\n    }\n  }\n}" /usr/local/conf/jobserver.conf
fi
```

in Terminal only then it is working fine but not when i am doing the same via shell script

This is my shell script

```
    #!bin/sh


    # Update jobserver config 
    if [ `grep -c 'pro-ad-assembly-0.1' /usr/local/conf/jobserver.conf` =  0 ]; then
            sed -i "\$aspark {\n  jobserver {\n    job-bin-paths {\n      ad-scala=\"/opt/scala/pro-ad-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\"\n    }\n  }\n}" /usr/local/conf/jobserver.conf
fi
```

AM i doing something wrong
Can anyone please help me

Comment: sed is good for parsing single lines. This is http://xyproblem.info/ . What are you really trying to do? (ie. updating config). To match multiple lines you need to append multiple lines to pattern space in sed using the `n` command.

Comment: `"\n"` and `'\n'` are two different things. You used the former but I suppose you wanted the latter.

Answer (score 0):

#!bin/sh

> sed -i '$ a spark { \n   jobserver {\n    job-bin-paths {\n   text here   }\n  }\n}"' test.txt

This is a sample script which gives an output in newline "\n".